# is any posibile save web html and restore from it?

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2

My question is how to save html all elements to localstorage and then close the browser,when next open this url it can restore from localstorage.
i have try  it and use jquery,but failed to meet my expectations.
`let nowPage = $('html').html()
  $('html').html(this.hispage)` 
the elements shows correct,but style has changed and all button has lose effect.

Answer (score 1):

Saving and trying to restore the rendered HTML string will not restore all of the data and event bindings that Vue needs to operate; you'll just wind up with static HTML.

Instead of trying to save the rendered result for a given application state, save the data that led to that state; have your Vue app initialize based on that saved data.

For example, let's say one of your components depends on the `isOpen` variable in its template:

```
<div v-if="isOpen">This panel is visible</div>
```

To store this page, instead of the rendered HTML, you'd store `isOpen`; and have the component read that value from localStorage in it `created()` or `mounted()`.  Repeat for any other variables the application depends on.

(If you are using vuex, you can automate or at least simplify this process using for example [vuex-persist-state](https://alligator.io/vuejs/vuex-persist-state/)).

(Meanwhile: in general be very wary of mixing jQuery with Vue: Vue won't know about and may overwrite any DOM modifications you perform in jQuery, and jQuery can easily overwrite data and event bindings that Vue depends on.  It's generally much better to manipulate the data underlying your app and let vue handle translating that into HTML, than to try to manipulate the HTML directly as jQuery code tends to do.)